# How does slicing numpy arrays with other arrays work?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array of shape `[batch_size, timesteps_per_samples, width, height]`, where width and height refer to a 2D grid. The values in this array can be interpreted as an elevation at a certain location that changes over time.
I want to know the elevation over time for various paths within this array. Therefore i have a second array of shape `[batch_size, paths_per_batch_sample, timesteps_per_path, coordinates]` (coordinates = 2, for x and y in the 2D plane).

The resulting array should be of shape `[batch_size, paths_per_batch_sample, timesteps_per_path]` containing the elevation over time for each sample within the batch.
The following two examples work. The first one is very slow and just serves for understanding what I am trying to do. I think the second one does what I want but I have no idea why this works nor if it may crash under certain circumstances.

Code for the problem setup:

```
import numpy as np

batch_size=32
paths_per_batch_sample=10
timesteps_per_path=4
width=64
height=64

elevation = np.arange(0, batch_size*timesteps_per_path*width*height, 1)
elevation = elevation.reshape(batch_size, timesteps_per_path, width, height)

paths = np.random.randint(0, high=width-1, size=(batch_size, paths_per_batch_sample, timesteps_per_path, 2))

range_batch = range(batch_size)
range_paths = range(paths_per_batch_sample)
range_timesteps = range(timesteps_per_path)
```

The following code works but is very slow:

```
elevation_per_time = np.zeros((batch_size, paths_per_batch_sample, timesteps_per_path))
for s in range_batch:
        for k in range_paths:
            for t in range_timesteps:
                x_co, y_co = paths[s,k,t,:].astype(int)
                elevation_per_time[s,k,t] = elevation[s,t,x_co,y_co]
```

The following code works (even fast) but I can't understand why and how o.0

```
elevation_per_time_fast = elevation[
        :,
        range_timesteps,
        paths[:, :, range_timesteps, 0].astype(int),
        paths[:, :, range_timesteps, 1].astype(int),
    ][range_batch, range_batch, :, :]
```

Prove that the results are equal

```
check = (elevation_per_time == elevation_per_time_fast)
print(np.all(check))
```

Can somebody explain how I can slice an nd-array by multiple other arrays?
Especially, I don't understand how the numpy knows that 'range_timesteps' has to run in step (for the index in axis 1,2,3).

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: because its not just indexing, its slicing. The result is still an array with multiple dimensions so you can still index it again afterwards.

Comment: @Eumel i updated the topic accordingly. Can you provide an answer for the very last question?

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a quick look at slicing numpy array first:

```
a = np.arange(0,9,1).reshape([3,3])
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Numpy has 2 ways of slicing array, full sections `start:stop` and by index from a list `[index1, index2 ...]`. The output will still be an array with the shape of your slice:

```
a[0:2,:]
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])

a[:,[0,2]]
array([[0, 2],
       [3, 5],
       [6, 8]])
```

The second part is that since you get a returned array with the same amount of dimensions you can easily stack any number of slices as long as you dont try to directly access an index outside of the array.

```
a[:][:][:][:][:][:][:][[0,2]][:,[0,2]]
array([[0, 2],
       [6, 8]])
```